# How to iterate through DevExpress Menu items in XtraBar?

Tags: devexpress

How to iterate through DevExpress Menu items in XtraBar ?

I need to iterate with a loop through all the menu items in xtrabar and i need to remove certain menu item on the way if some conditions are satisfied ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) might know..

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
    foreach (DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem item in bar.Manager.Items)
    {
       //Do sth.
    }
```

Comment: If you are only interested in BarButtonItems you might want to add
  "if (item is BarButtonItem)" inside the loop.